# vue composition api toRefs typescript

Tags: typescript, vue-composition-api

How to get proper type when creating a ref for props? I have tried like this

```
setup(props) {
    const { userId } = toRefs(props); // userId is string
    retrun {
        ...getComposition(userId);
    };
}

...
function getComposition(userId) {
    // How to make sure that userId.value is string?)
    const caps = userId.value.toUperCase(); // here how to get string method hints
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#using-with-composition-api

> Refs infer the type from the initial value:

But I think an IDE can get confused just like us. Anyway, this works for me in webstorm...

```
  setup (props) {
    const { userId } = toRefs(props); // userId is string
    function getComposition(idRef) {
      return {caps: (idRef.value as string).toUpperCase()};
    }
    return {
      ...getComposition(userId)
    };
  }
```

[vue devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxgBN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Personnally, I think you shouldn't use toRefs() for props, because toRefs result is a writable ref object, but `props` is supposed not to be mutated.
So that I think it's better to pass `props.userId` to `getComposition` function then vscode can easily recoginize the type of this props.